# Define standard instances of a class inside itself (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, subclass

I'm trying to make my own Vector3 class (class of 3D vectors), but I found a little problem.
My goal is to define:

```
static const Vector3 zero = Vector3 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
static const Vector3 one = Vector3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

inside of Vector3 class, so I can access them by:

```
Vector3::zero;
Vector3::one;
```

But it seems (if I understand the problem) that I can't declare a class instance inside of the same class (like a Vector3 in Vector3 definition), probably because when I declare zero and one, the definition of Vector3 itself is not concluded yet.
Do you know any workaround to solve this problem? I prefer, if possible, not to use any function returning Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) or Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), but to use a static const variable without additional computation

Comment: Why would a Vector3 class need to contain a Vector3 instance? It sounds like there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I would say its quite common to have sentinel values, shorthand expressions or common math constants inside the class scope, since they're constant expressions of the complex type.

Answer (score 8):

You can declare them within the class, but you also have to define and initialize them outside.

```
// In a header file:
class Vector3 {
public:
  Vector3(double, double, double);

  static const Vector3 zero;
  static const Vector3 one;
};

// In some source file:
#include "vector3.h"
const Vector3 Vector3::zero(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const Vector3 Vector3::one(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```